# What gamma to use to calibrate MacBook Pro 2016 display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I use the X-Rite i1Display Pro colorimeter to calibrate all my monitors and I want to calibrate my 2016 MacBook Pro, but I'm not sure if I should stick to the 2.2 gamma settings or raise it to the 2.6 DCI-P3 color space gamma settings because apple automatically converts SRGB values into DCI-P3 colors space to perform matching by using Gamma 2.2 while preserving 2.6 for DCI-P3 tagged content.

Does anyone know which one is best to use?

Comment: What is your end goal in calibration forgetting the specific MacBook? Are you going to press or handing off work digitally? Or is this more about you and your eyes while working on your projects day to day and month to month?

Comment: @bmike right now it would be for my eyes and working on projects day to day. I might do some work with affinity photo later on to enhance photos for my own website, but nothing too crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, as it's too long to be a comment, but not authoritative enough to be a full answer...

I've not worked in P3 at all - but for sRGB, Adobe98 or ProPhoto the general 'rule' is to set your monitor to default & let the i1Profiler handle it from there - I guess for a laptop monitor, that would be done automatically as the OS gives up control to the Profiler.
It will usually correctly self-detect your monitor's capabilities.

Use the Advanced settings for finer control, especially to use a larger colour Patch Set, which I've found can make quite a difference. [tbh, some of the settings in advanced you will just stare at blankly - for those, just go with default ;)

Your Photoshop etc workflow should always be set to keep your input profile, so you only ever go to sRGB at 'Export For Web' or the newer 'Export As...'.
So long as you allow Photoshop to handle your working space, as sRGB, Adobe98 or ProPhoto [& never set your monitor profile to it! ] then your workflow should be good from start to finish.

BTW, your monitor profile is always applied "live" to the screen by any colour-management-capable software & should never be in your actual workflow, only in your system Display Prefs, which the Profiler ought to set for you when you save the profile.

If you need to regularly output to specific ICC profiles, then make sure they are in `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Proofing/` & you can soft-proof with gamut warning much more easily.
If your output will be to sRGB, then no amount of profiling will actually make it faithfully transition to the rest of the world, because of the range of horribly approximate devices it will be reproduced on.

Profiling your camera would be a separate QA & would need a ColorChecker Passport etc.